# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor\Widget_Base' not found

Tags: wordpress, widget, elementor

I am trying to make a plugin and it gives me fatal error Widget_Base cannot be found. I am a beginner, this is the snippet of the code:

```
<?php
namespace CustomDesignPlugin;

use Elementor\Widget_Base;
use Elementor\Controls_Manager;

class Custom_Design_Widget extends Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'custom-design-widget';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return __('Custom Design Widget', 'custom-design');
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'eicon-button';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return ['general'];`
```

It says the error in line 7 at 'class Custom_Design_Widget extends Widget_Base'

I tried adding lines of code from different posts, none of them worked for me.